# Integrate to Magento to offer shipping

Tags: api, shipping, b2b

I've just started working at a logistics company and some of our new clients uses the Magento platform.

I've been looking through the API documentation in search of instructions on how to offer shipping quotes, receive orders etc, but I was unable to find it.

Can someone point me to the link in which I can find such documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here you can find the answer

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/shipping-settings-basic.html